# iis site connect to database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, web-services, iis

I have a **C# WCF project,which contains a database(sql) and webservice**,
everything is working fine in the debugger, but once i use the iis(published by file system in vs2015), the webservice cannot make changes in the database,**SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred**
(i am assuming because the connection string is different, current one is:
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Workspace\WebService\WebService\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
what would be the correct connection string? or is it something else?
thanks

Comment: Multiple possibilities... Main reason would be that `iis has no enough permissions to that file.`

Comment: how do i make it so iis has enough permissions?

Comment: Check the properties of the folder. It will have the a section for security and permissions. Check if it has iis user.